# Thunder client subscription git sync capability

Tags: visual-studio, thunderclient

Can someone explain the difference in the git sync capability of thunder client "subscription"?

On their github page it states that the git sync capabilities are "subscription" only.  I've played around with the instructions for saving your configuration to your project workspace , but I don't have a subscription and everything seem to work.  Is it more of an honor system with all the capabilities available on download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you need subscription to use Git sync from Aug 18th, 2023

https://github.com/rangav/thunder-client-support/releases/tag/v2.7.0

Comment: It is a shame that these thunder client guy is hijacking the data of long time users suddenly. Forcing them to taking a subscription. It is a shame!

Comment: Imagine being so underhand that you paywall a feature people have been using free for years when all it does is write a JSON file to a directory on the user's own filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your settings to use "global" thunderclient directory and run this to point your local(repository) thunder-client dir to "global"

`curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/PauloLeal/2756be58b9827cd8e3aaeee55d9ad27a/raw/8c354654b0bf0142cc1f7f25a6010a7cc57c57d9/fix-thunder-client-git.sh | sh` (linux and mac)

You will need to do this for every repository you want to use thunderclient. If you work with different repos at same time, it will be a pain in the 4ss but works for now.